# Mute hidden div (video) html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I'm using a video div hidden on a webpage and toogle its visibility using javascript keypress. When the page loads even if the div is hidden I can still hear the sound.
1. is it possible to mute the sound when the div is hidden ?
or
2. is it possible to start/stop the playback when I toggle div visibility ?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == 116) {
    // if the user pressed 't':
    $('div').toggle();
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure your video element doesn't have autoplay enabled, and/or set to mute. When you toggle the div use .play to start the video and .stop to stop it when hiding the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a full answer, you should make sure that your `<video />` tag doesn't have an `autoplay` attribute to keep it from starting as soon as the page loads, and give it an `id` attribute so you can access it. Then you can use some basic javascript when a user toggles the visibility to start/pause playback:

To play, you can:

```
document.getElementById('your-video-id').play();
```

And to pause:

```
document.getElementById('your-video-id').pause();
```

So your keypress function could then become:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  // Grab a reference to your video
  var video = document.getElementById('your-video-id');

   if (key == 116) {         
     // if the user pressed 't':
     $('div').toggle();

     // Check if the video is paused, if it is then play, if it's playing then pause.
    if(video.paused){
      video.play();
    } else {
      video.pause();
    }

   }
});
```

Comment: Works. Is there a way to reset the video to play always from the beginning ?

Comment: You should be able to set the currentTime property of the video to 0 after you pause it on toggle. 

So `else { video.pause(); video.currentTime=0; }`